# Why does gradient descent outperform closed form solution

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

In Andrew Ng's machine learning course, in exercise 3 he uses gradient descent (or some other iterative algorithm?) to find coefficients for a problem of handwritten number classification. I repeated his approach, and got success rate ~95%, which is even little improving if I increase the number of iterations (50 -> 90, 0.7%).

I also tried to find that coefficients by solving the system of equation: $X'X\, \theta = X'y$, and success rate in this case is 89.3%. I'm quite surprised that closed form solution is outperformed by iterational approach so significantly. Things are even more weird for me because Andrew uses regularization, and if I add some to the closed form solution, my success rate appears as low as 78%.

Could someone please help me get an idea of what happens there? Is it numerical stability issue, or I miss something completely?

For my exercise, I use Octave 4.4.1 as:

```
beta = linsolve(xx'*xx, xx'*yy)
```

or

```
beta = pinv(xx'*xx)*xx'*yy
```

and get the same 89%.

Thanks for any ideas.

PS. Success rate is the accuracy of the algorithm on the training set.

https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome

Comment: Is Andrew fitting a linear regression? I ask because your explicit solution would compute the optimal weights in a *linear* regression fit to the data, but I would suspect that Andrew is using a logistic regression.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @yury If you feel that you know the answer to this question, you can write an answer.